# Is there a keyboard shortcut to refresh project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, pydev, eclipse-cdt

I am looking for something other than right clicking on the project and then Refresh all option. Because its painful. I'm using an older version of Eclipse (v3.5).

Comment: I'm looking for this too.

Answer (score 3):

It's not ideal, but 'Shift-Alt-Q, P' (do the shift-alt-q combination, release all of the keys and then press 'p') brings you to the package explorer, where if you hit F5 while your project is selected, will refresh that whole project.

Like I said, not ideal, but the best I've been able to come up with.

Comment: yeah, there really should be a shortcut for this, especially as projects have more and more external file changing/refreshing going on

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't F5 work?

CTRL+SHIFT+L should list the keyboard shortcuts available.

Comment: Select the project then hit F5.

Comment: that works! but I was looking for a keyboard only solution? looks like its not possible?

Comment: I don't know if F5 (the standard Windows refresh shortcut) ever worked on OS X, but it does not work on Mountain Lion with Eclipse version Kepler (Standard/SDK, Kepler Service Release 1). Neither does Apple-R, the standard Apple refresh shortcut. Grr.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I can't offer an ideal solution, but an option for Windows users that find this frustrating and want a 'minimal key press' solution.

I managed to write a script for [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) that will listen to the Win+F5 key when Eclipse is the active window. If it detects the Win+F5 key, it will automatically do Brian Gruber's technique: Shift-Alt-Q, P, (EDIT 20/02/2020: I added a press of the 'Home' key, to assure the top-most project node in the package explorer is selected), followed by F5, and then followed by F12, to bring focus back to the editor.

"**eclipse_Win_F5_refresh.ahk**"

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class SWT_Window0
; Win+F5 = Refresh Eclipse project
$#F5::
Send, !+q
Send, p
Send, Home
Send, {F5}
Send, {F12}
return
```

So then it's just a matter of:

1. Save the script to a file
2. Install [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
3. Double-click the script file to run it
4. Press Win-key+F5 in eclipse to get your project refresh